# MS SQL Code optimation in an stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Is there a shorter/better way of doing this (putting the "SELECT..." inside the IF statement?):

```
SELECT @varA = COLUMN1
FROM    TABLE
WHERE   COLUMN2 = @varX

IF @varA <> @varB
BEGIN
    DO SOMETHING
    RETURN 
END
```

varB is comming through an input parameter.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [TABLE] WHERE [COLUMN2] <>@varB)
BEGIN
   DO SOMETHING
    RETURN 
END
```

Comment: yeah, thought about the same a second ago. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **case when** statement. It will concise your query.

But if you have to perform multiple operations, **if** statement is better option.